# How do you acces the lighting data for the scene in unity shader graph?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I am working on a shader, and need to access the lighting data in the scene. Is there any way to do that? Ideally it would not be using a light textures because I also need it to account for moving light sources.

I have looked around for a bit, but I have not seen anything that would work yet.